# RxJS: Difference between auditTime and sampleTime?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive

I can't find any relevant posts about this and I can't figure out the nuance from the documentation, what is the difference between auditTime and sampleTime operators?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### auditTime

`auditTime(ms)` will keep storing the latest value for `ms` milliseconds. After `ms` have passed, if any value exists, it will pass along as a `next notification`.

`auditTime(ms) === audit(() => timer(ms, scheduler?))`.

```
u - units of time

1--3--5----------6-7-- values$
----|-----|----!-----| auditTime(5u)
----3-----5----------7 result

^     ^          ^

! - since the timer did not started, because there was no value after `5`, there won't be any value emitted further in the stream

^ - when the timer starts
```

It's also worth noticing that this *timer* starts only when at least one value has arrived.

Maybe visualizing the [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/2365a54c391d9ef76ddc417f8f6dedb17cdb890e/src/internal/operators/audit.ts#L86-L104) would help:

```
_next(value: T): void {
  this.value = value; // Keep track of the oldest value
  this.hasValue = true;
  if (!this.throttled) { // If the timer didn't started yet, start it
    let duration;
    try {
      const { durationSelector } = this;
      duration = durationSelector(value); // Create observable; if `auditTime(d)`, it will be `() => timer(ms)`
    } catch (err) {
      return this.destination.error(err);
    }
    const innerSubscription = subscribeToResult(this, duration); // Subscribe to the inner observable
    /* ... */
    this.throttled = innerSubscription // Store the subscription
  }
}
```

When the timer expires(i.e when the inner observable has emitted/completed), the value will be passed along:

```
// Called when the inner obs completes/emits a value
clearThrottle() {
  const { value, hasValue, throttled } = this;
  if (throttled) { // Did we have a timer(a subscription)? If yes, unsubscribe 
    this.remove(throttled);
    this.throttled = null;
    throttled.unsubscribe();
  }
  if (hasValue) { // If we have a value, send it do its destination
    this.value = null;
    this.hasValue = false;
    this.destination.next(value);
  }
}
```

---

#### sampleTime

`sampleTime(ms)`, like `auditTime(ms)` will keep track of the latest arrived value and will emit it further in the chain, with the **exception** that in `sampleTime` the `timer`(which decides when to `emit` the value) is always active. This means that no matter if any value as arrived since the **last emission**, the timer will run. Now, if no new value arrived, it will simply not pass along the value.

Let's explore its [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/2365a54c391d9ef76ddc417f8f6dedb17cdb890e/src/internal/operators/sampleTime.ts#L78-L89):

```
_next(value: T) { // Keep track of the oldest value
  this.lastValue = value;
  this.hasValue = true;
}

notifyNext() { // When time is up, check if any `new` value came in since the last 'sample' 
  if (this.hasValue) { // If we have a value, then send it further
    this.hasValue = false;
    this.destination.next(this.lastValue);
  }
}
```

Note that the value can be the same as the one which was previously emitted, but it must arrive while the current timer is active.

`sampleTime` by default uses `AsyncAction`s, which are *managed* by the `AsyncScheduler`. Put differently, the `timer`, in this case, is achieved with `setInterval`.

`sample(notifier)` follows the same logic, except that there is no scheduler, and the `timer` is defined by the `notifier`, which is an `Observable`.

Compared to `auditTime`:

```
u - units of time

1--3--5-------6-7-- values$
----|---|---|---|-- auditTime(5u)
----3---5-------7-- result

^   ^   ^   ^   ^

^ - when the timer starts
```

Comment: You meant to use `sampleTime(5u)` in your last diagram, didn't you?

Comment: @AlexeyGrinko yes!