# Why is my Observable emitting more values than expected, and why is auditTime a fix?

Tags: redux, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I asked a question here recently about observables and you guys were of really great help (as always). Now I'm having a similar situation, and me and my team-mate are bending our brains over it.

The bug to fix was: user sees a collection of assets, and on browser refresh the wrong set of assets was being loaded. It turns out the key to the problem was one particular pipe observing the currently selected collection. Here's the relevant code:

```
this.selectedCollection.pipe(
  filter((v) => !!v)).subscribe((v) => {
    console.log('PIPE: selected collection', v.collectionId);
    this.store.dispatch(
      // action jackson on redux
    )
  );
});
```

The action to be dispatched here is for loading the assets of the collection. One collection was always loaded first as default and it was conflicting with further selections made by the user.

I've also added console.logs on the relevant reducers and effect to visualize behavior.

What happens on browser refresh is this:

[image]

Collection *9-em...* is the default collection we don't want to see, and collection *9uem...* is the user's choice whose asset's we want to see.

The first five lines show the expected output of the observable:

- default collection set as selected collection
- reducer 'is loading' assets
- the user triggers a change selected collection action
- the selected collection value is being updated and emitted accordingly

Now we would have expected the effect to load the assets and that's it. But what happens is that the pipe keeps emitting the same values once again, which is weird, because I'm 100% sure no further value is being set from anywhere. But it would also be fine, since we end up with the desired value. Yet strangely, the reducer is handling the load actions in reverse order, which led to the wrong assets being loaded (this could be a whole different issue on top).

Adding *auditTime(200)* as first operator to the pipe above fixed the issue. No further values were emitted.

Now, my questions are:

- Why are the values emitted twice? Could it be an inappropriate operator/subscription some place else (didn't see anything suspicious)?
- And why is *auditTime(200)* magically fixing this?

The effect also works as a pipe of actions being filtered, and it contains an *auditTime(200)* operator before executing, so that it executes only on the last action. While I do understand on principle what it does, I'm not quite sure if using *auditTime* like that just because it works is such a good idea.

I assume this is an issue out of noob confusion resulting in using rxjs not the right way. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything useful on google. I really don't like 'fixing' a bug by adding a line of code that I just don't understand.

Thank you so much in advance!

As requested by fridoo, here's the code for *this.selectedCollection*:

```
get selectedCollection(): Observable<collectionState.CollectionsData> {
  return this.store
     .select(collectionState.getSelectedCollection)
     .pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
}
```

And for *getSelectedCollection*:

```
export const getSelectedCollection: (state: any) => CollectionsData = (state: any) =>
getCollectionsState(state)
  ? getCollectionsState(state).selectedCollection
  : undefined;
```

The rest is pretty forward just objects of state, the observable created via the select method. We're not using any library for redux (not my decision), so select is implemented like this:

```
select<T>(fn: (state: any) => T): Observable<T> {
  return this.state$.pipe(map(fn), distinctUntilChanged());
}
```

Does this help any further?

Comment: I'd say this is a very interesting situation and I think it would be much easier to find the solution(and the problem) if you could reproduce it in a StackBlitz app or something similar. In the meanwhile, you might find interesting [RxJS: Difference between auditTime and sampleTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61567579/rxjs-difference-between-audittime-and-sampletime/61569731#61569731).

Comment: Please include the code for `this.selectedCollection`

Comment: Hi fridoo, thanks for your comment. I've added the code.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Andrei. This is well explained, much better than the documentation of rxjs which I often find rather confusing. :)

I'm gonna ponder on how this would affect the issue at hand.